# Extracting data in columnar form from a tab separated file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have tab separated file that is in gzip format. i am trying to read it by converting into columnar form using pandas. When i am trying to read a particular column, i getting only first row as output. There is no header in the file.
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('example.gz', compression='gzip',header=0,sep='\t')
cols =[2]
xml_file = df.columns[cols]
for i in xml_file:
    print(i)
```

There are 20 rows in my file but i am getting only the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do:

```
xml_file=df[df.columns[cols]]
```

Comment: I tried this already. Its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
cols = 2
xml_file = df.loc[:, cols]
```

Or:

```
cols = 2
xml_file = df[cols]
```